# How to require properties only on create entity in loopback4

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a model with required properties but are only required on create, on update only the id property es required. 
This is my model example:

```
@model()
export class MyModel extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  id: string;
}
```

On Mongoose schemas i can define a context to validate params but on Loopback 4 documentation i can't found nothing like this to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried excluding the id property from the @requestBody decorator of the parameter of the request controller

```
@requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Model, {exclude: ['id']}),
        },
      },
    }
```

Add this as a parameter to the method of the controller

Or

YOu can create a custom schema for the request body something like

```
const RequestSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  required: ['name'],
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    id: {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
};

export const RequestBody = {
  required: true,
  content: {
    'application/json': {schema: RequestSchema},
  },
};
```

See how only the name is required and Id is not in the RequestSchema Object

then pass it to the controller method as

```
@requestBody(RequestSchema)
```

Hopefully, this shall work.
Write me if this also not fixes the problem.
Thanks